# Can one use Writing Meta as a sandbox for Writing Beta?

Tags: discussion, support

I recently figured out that Writing Beta doesn't have a sandbox feature like WB does. Now, people said this was due to WB being a rather different site, therefore requiring such a feature. But still I have a question that I am not sure is fit for Writing Beta. It would be really helpful to get some looks on it before posting it there. So, can I use Writing Meta for trying out my question?

Comment: Definitely check out [Should we create a sandbox for questions](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1342/2533), particularly [Neil Fein's answer](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1344/2533) to that question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes! Meta exists to talk about the site, and IMO proposing and developing questions definitely counts.

While there's nothing wrong with just asking a question on the main site and asking for edits or suggestions, having a question closed/edited is a bigger deal for some people than others. I can see why having another place to sketch out questions is helpful.

I'm not opposed to creating a sandbox feature, but I think the community here is too small to warrant it. I'm fine with people using meta as a sandbox, or asking about proposed questions on chat. If we get a larger community in the future, we can revisit this.

Comment: *"If we get a larger community in the future, we can revisit this."* I agree 100% with that. Let's not see a "we don't need (or have the community to support) a special sandbox post on Meta" as a "we shouldn't ever have a special sandbox post on Meta". If circumstances change, a decision can (almost) always be revisited. Heck, there were the writing challenges...